# Click using Javascript in Chrome

Tags: javascript, click

I am trying to click on page two using JS

https://www.abbreviations.com/sr

So I opened the console and put

```
document.getElementsByClassName('rc5')[1].click();
```

But it didn't click it and go to that page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".pager > .rc5")[1].click()
```

Answer (score 0):

what kind action you want to get as your 'click' result? first, it may be important to determine, that browser defines clicks as 'native' and 'generated by the code' and in the case of security and browsers policies.

but there is one smart method to work with DOM - headless browsers, like [puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer).

you can do really anything with the webpage, using pure javascript.